# select month and year from Date of birth IN sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

i have table with DOB column ('2012-05-29 00:00:00.000') and few other fields , i need to select the data for DOB between 6 months to 6 Years. I tried using the below SQL but this is not giving me the right data. any help will be appreciated.

```
select * from dbo.xyz
where ( FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MONTH, birth_date , GETDATE()) % 12) >=6
      AND  FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, birth_date , GETDATE()) / 365.25) <= 6
      )
```

Comment: Are you trying to find rows where the DOB is > 6 months prior to the current date and < 6 months prior to the current date? What is the point of using FLOOR here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from dbo.xyz
where DATEDIFF(MONTH, birth_date , GETDATE()) between 6 and 72
```

Comment: This is logically correct but is nonSARGable because it will have to evaluate the datediff for every single row.

Answer (score 3):

When using dates, the advice is to use functions only on the non-column values.  In other words, modify `getdate()`, not `birth_date`:

```
select *
from dbo.xyz
where birth_date between dateadd(year, -6,  getdate()) and dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
```

This has two advantages.  First, it makes the `where` clause "sargable", which means an index can be used on the comparison.  More importantly, the alternative of using `datediff()` doesn't quite work as expected.  `datediff()` counts the number of *calendar boundaries* between two values.  So, 2014-12-31 and 2015-01-01 are one day apart, one month apart, and even one year apart.

Comment: thanks for the calendar boundaries explanation Gordon.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option that will allow indexing on birthdate.

```
select *
from dbo.xyz
where birthdate > DATEADD(YEAR, -6, GETDATE())
    and birthdate < DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
```